# Does the typeof() operator in C# allocate a new Type object on the heap, or return an existing one?

Tags: c#, reflection, garbage-collection, xna, typeof

Should be pretty self-explanatory, but this is in the context of real-time XNA code where I want to avoid allocations in order to avoid triggering GC. So I'm wondering if the managed Type objects associated with the types that have been loaded are always present in the runtime, or if typeof() actually constructs a new Type object (presumably from some unmanaged metadata in the runtime) on the heap, which will be garbage collected. Feel free to point out any ignorant assumptions/misconceptions revealed by even asking this question as well =)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, types are cached, it returns always the same static readonly instance.

You can write this sample test program to verify this :)

```
static void MyTest()
{
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(typeof(int), typeof(int))
        Console.WriteLine("Yippie! they are the same!");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("WTF?");
}
```

The same apply for GetType method and for every other reflection function, like getting properties, methods, fields, attributes and everything else.

Comment: Thanks (to you and Jon both)! I really should've thought of this test - my self-serving excuse is that as a sometime functional programming weenie I tend to think of reference equality as an ugly hack, and so it doesn't always cross my mind when it would be useful =)

Comment: @MaxStrini: as apologetics go, that was a nicely fabricated one

Comment: This doesn't show that it's guaranteed to always be the case. You could use the same sort of test in Java to prove that autoboxing always returned the same numbers - it's true up to a point, but guaranteed for a particular range. Or this could just be the current implementation, with a change in the future... I always prefer a guarantee from a specification.

Comment: This is something that likely will never change because is built in the compiler and in the framework itself. When an assembly is loaded, ar types are loaded. I keep it as a warranty. The language specification is a different thing than real world, language specification must be as much as open possible to let other projects become "language compliant" more easily :)

Comment: And I must also say that it is become a de-facto thing, is a de-facto standard that typeof and gettype returns the same instance, and microsoft cannot change it because it will break down all possible programs (and their framework itself).

Answer (score 21):

From the C# 4 spec section 7.6.11:

> There is only one `System.Type` object for any given type. This means that for a type `T`, `typeof(T) == typeof(T)` is always true.

(Additionally, if you get the type via reflection it will always fetch the same `Type` object too, but that's not in the spec.)

Comment: Strange the specification would express it as `typeof(T) == typeof(T)` when that could just mean the `==` operator was overloaded! :)

Comment: Yes exactly, the C# specification keeps it large enough to contain every kind of situation. This can happen for several reasons... you can implement the Type class in your custom type system inheriting from basic System.Reflection classes. You can then behave differently (if you are crazy and really, really need that). However in the standards implementation of the framework (Mono, .NET compact framework, microsoft .net framework all versions, silverlight) all the reflection methods behave in the same way and returns the same instance.