# Does t.GetType() return the same Type instance?

Tags: c#, types

I'm thinking about storing a `Type` variable in my objects. However, there can be quite a lot of them, but the amount of different types is not so large. I'm worried about using a lot of memory to store the `Type` in all those objects, when the type could be the same for many of them.

Is a new instance of `Type` created every time I look up the type of something, with either `t.GetType()` or `typeof(T)`? Or is it actually the same? If it was the same I wouldn't have to worry about the memory.

Note that I have considered generics, which is not an alternative in this case.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[MSDN: Object.GetType Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gettype):

> For two objects x and y that have identical runtime types, `Object.ReferenceEquals(x.GetType(),y.GetType())` returns true.

So, yes.

Comment: Is this also valid for `typeof(T)`? I can't find anything in the docs about it.

Comment: That's a different question, but yes, see [Does the typeof() operator in C# allocate a new Type object on the heap, or return an existing one?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856061/does-the-typeof-operator-in-c-sharp-allocate-a-new-type-object-on-the-heap-or).

Comment: @DavidS. JLRishe's answer is more relevant there.

Comment: @Kendall that answer just states some code and claims without any references, I don't see how that is more relevant.

Comment: I was just referring to the fact that the answer includes `typeof`.

Comment: @Kendall I initially only answered the question title and in the meantime I was searching for an answer to the typeof question.

Answer (score 4):

There is only one instance for each type. If you evaluate:

```
"hello".GetType() == typeof(String)
```

or

```
Object.ReferenceEquals("hello".GetType(), typeof(String))
```

You will get the value `true`.

This works with generics as well:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
// same will have the value true
bool same = Object.ReferenceEquals(dict.GetType(), typeof(Dictionary<string, string>));
```

Comment: CodeCaster's answer is more relevant here.

Comment: This does not mean they are the same object, the equality operator can be overloaded. For example, the equality operator will return true for two different instances of string containing an identical string.

Comment: @YvesDubois @DStanley `object.ReferenceEquals` proves it.

Comment: @KendallFrey Indeed it does! But, when I made my comment, there was no mention of `object.ReferenceEquals`. Also, my point about the equality operator still stands; it is not a correct proof.