# Will the Type Object be garbage collected?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, clr

For example, I have a Class A and a method f.

```
Class B
{
    void aMethod(){}    
}

void f()
{
    var a= new B();
    a.aMethod();
}
```

When execute a method, the CLR will first initiate essential type objects on heap. Thus before the first statement in f execute, an object `B Type Object` will be allocated and initialized on heap.

So after f has been executed, will the `B Type Object` be garbage collected?(Does `B Type Object` has some special `root` other than the `B` Instance?)

For clarification, `B Type Object` refers the `System.Type` object that represents the `B` type

I am reading chapter 4 of the book `CLR via C#`.

Comment: What do you mean by "type object?" Are you talking about the instance of `B` stored in `a`, or are you talking about the `System.Type` object that represents the `B` type?

Comment: @cdhowie I mean the `System.Type` object that represents the `B` type.

Comment: _"So after f has been executed, will the B Type Object be garbage collected?"_ - short answer _yes_ but **not immediately**.  _When_ is up to the CLR and is a complex subject

Comment: @MickyD Could you please recommend some key words or links of articles for me? I am reading the CLR via C# book. However, it seems I need some extra info to grasp the book.

Comment: @AlexWei I don't know the exact answer, but I would suspect that `System.Type` objects are never garbage collected. They are lightweight, anyway.

Comment: [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856061/does-the-typeof-operator-in-c-sharp-allocate-a-new-type-object-on-the-heap-or) (if I understand yours, that is).

Comment: @John Thanks. However it is a different question for me. The link can only prove they are same but talk nothing about their lifetime. My guess of it is same as cdhowie.They are never gc. But I can't find any reference nor solution to prove it.

Comment: _[Fundamentals of garbage collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals)_

Comment: The answer is yes. However it will only be collected when the GC feels the need

Comment: @MickyD Thanks. It will take some time for me to read it. I thought `Type Object` has some special `Root` which always exists.

Comment: @mjwills I recently worked a project (already failed part because of optimization)which heavily depends on a IL Intepreter Runtime project. I have tried optimize my project without dive deep into the dependent project which didn't work. So I thought I should dive deep into the dependent project codebase and see what I can do. Most code make no sense to me. I find some clues on the web have a good understanding this book will understand the project better. So what I do now is try as much as I can to read this book.

Comment: @mjwills I thought singe piece of knowledge which may seem no meaningful may become meaningful when connected altogether when I read the code again. But maybe I was wrong. There are better ways to achieve it which beyond my knowledge base.

Comment: The thing to keep in mind is that the CLR doesn't have to play by the same rule as you. Metadata is not handled in the same manner as regular object instances.

Comment: Type objects are cached, specifically to make reflection more performant.  Important, digging through the metadata to construct a Type isn't very fast with high odds for page faults.  This is a complete implementation detail that should never make any difference to your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the `f()` method finishes, the instance of the `B` object created in the method becomes *eligible* for collection. That doesn't necessarily mean it will be collected right away. It will be collected whenever the GC happens to run next, which may or may not be when the method finishes.

But it also sounds like maybe you're talking about metadata, another kind of object instance used to describe object types, such as the [`Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type?view=netframework-4.8) type.

So we need to talk about both things: `Type` instances and metadata. There is no `Type` instance just because you called the `f()` method and used a `B` object for the first time. There **is** metadata for each type, but it does not generally live on the heap, per se, and certainly isn't allocated only because you called `f()` for the first time. Rather, all of the metadata for a particular assembly lives in a table in the object code for the assembly. The entire table is loaded with the assembly. You can read more about it here:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metadata_(CLI)

It's confusing, because there is also an `Object` type, which means something completely different in .Net, and the use of the word `Object` in the question confuses things more than it helps. But the `Object` type in .Net is not automatically rooted in any special way. When instances are no longer reachable, they become eligible for collection just like anything else.

Comment: Generic types can be created at runtime; I don't think they are ever eligible for collection, but most programs don't create enough of them for that to be a problem.

Comment: Yes, and assemblies can be loaded at runtime, adding more metadata to the table. But neither is part of the example code in the question and I suspect will only further confuse the OP.

Comment: Does the `Object` type you mentioned refer to the one contain `Type object ptr` and `Sync block index`? And The `Object` type is a instance of the `Type` type  which is in the metadata and always exists. Do I understand you right?

Comment: `After the f() method finishes, the instance of the B object created in the method becomes eligible for collection.` Technically it can be eligible even before that point. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cbrumme/lifetime-gc-keepalive-handle-recycling/