# Under which conditions Marshal.SizeOf allocates on the heap?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mono, marshalling, unmanaged-memory

So I have very weird tracing data from **dotTrace**:
[image]

Here is the struct:

```cs
public struct TargetStruct : SomeInterface
{
    private RigidTransform rt;
    public RoundBounds rb;
    public int Start;
    public Bool IsEnabled;
    public TypeEnum TheType;
}
//
// Nested types
//
public struct RoundBounds : SomeInterface
{
    public float3 Center;
    public float Radius;
    public float RadiusSq;
}
public struct Bool : IEquatable<Bool>, SomeInterface
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
    private bool value;
}
public enum TypeEnum : byte
{
    None,
    Type1,
    Type1
}
public struct RigidTransform
{
    public quaternion rot;
    public float3 pos;
    public static readonly RigidTransform identity = new RigidTransform(new quaternion(0f, 0f, 0f, 1f), new float3(0f, 0f, 0f));
}
```

This runs under Unity's mono [2019.4.12-mbe](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/mono/tree/unity-2019.4-mbe), if it is relevant, Unity generates project targeting 4.7.1. Struct is being passed down to SizeOf via generic methods with constraints `where T: struct`, though this should be irrelevant.

Here is IL of mono's mscorlib `Marshal.SizeOf<T>`:
[image]
Call is forwarded to external `SizeOf(Type t);`

What can possible cause heap allocations? My only assumption is boxing, but I cant see any boxing here. `GetType()` [should not allocate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856061/does-the-typeof-operator-in-c-sharp-allocate-a-new-type-object-on-the-heap-or)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you refer to regarding the allocation behavior of `GetType()` says that it doesn't allocate a new instance every time, it does *not* say it doesn't allocate at all.

The first time you call `GetType()` on an object of a particular type will result in the allocation of a new `RuntimeType` instance to represent the type, but it's a one-off allocation and subsequent `GetType()` calls on objects of that type will return the existing instance.

Comment: Hmm, I di more testing and noticed it still alocates on consequent runs. Any more ideas as to why this might happen?

Comment: @KreonZZ - in my tests it only allocated on the first call to `GetType()`. If you're seeing something different you're going to need to give more details in terms of your exact code that calls `Marshal.SizeOf<T>()` and how you are measuring allocations.

Comment: Nothing special about the code, it gets the generic T constrained to struct then calls Marshal. I made a hashset to check how many unique types and it just 20. Twenty ypes cant product 3Mb of GetSize garbage, I think there is something about mono I dont know

Answer (score 0):

Take dotMemory and profile your application with "Collect memory allocation and traffic data from start" option enabled. Then look at ["Allocations" view](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dotmemory/Analyze_Memory_Allocation.html). It'll show you all allocations with accuracy to byte/object.

Could you please tell me if data in dotMemory/dotTrace differs in your case?